# regexp split string by commas and spaces, but ignore the inside quotes and parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I need split string by commas and spaces, but ignore the inside quotes, single quotes and parentheses

```
$str = "Questions, \"Quote\",'single quote','comma,inside' (inside parentheses) space #specialchar";
```

so that the resultant array will have

```
[0]Questions
[1]Quote
[2]single quote
[3]comma,inside
[4]inside parentheses
[5]space
[6]#specialchar
```

my atual regexp is

```
$tags = preg_split("/[,\s]*[^\w\s]+[\s]*/", $str,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

but this is ignoring special chars and stil split the commas inside quotes, the resultant array is :

```
[0]Questions
[1]Quote
[2]single quote
[3]comma
[4]inside
[5]inside parentheses
[6]space
[7]specialchar
```

ps: this is no csv

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work only for non-nested parentheses:

```
    $regex = <<<HERE
    /  "  ( (?:[^"\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+ ) \"
     | '  ( (?:[^'\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+ ) \'
     | \( ( [^)]*                  ) \)
     | [\s,]+
    /x
    HERE;

    $tags = preg_split($regex, $str, -1,
                         PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
                       | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The `++` and `*+` will consume as much as they can and give nothing back for backtracking. This technique is described in [perlre(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) as the most efficient way to do this kind of matching.

Comment: inshallah. do you know the same regexp for using in javascript split() function? it would be nice if you could tell me then.

Comment: @unknown, I think the `/x` flag and the `*+` and `++` quantifiers may not be supported, so, lose the `/x` flag and strip any whitespace (including newlines), and instead of the `*+` and `++` quantifiers use only `*` and `+` respectively.

Comment: 2023 and stll going strong. nice

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works for the data you supplied:

```
$rgx = <<<'EOT'
/
  [,\s]++
  (?=(?:(?:[^"]*+"){2})*+[^"]*+$)
  (?=(?:(?:[^']*+'){2})*+[^']*+$)
  (?=(?:[^()]*+\([^()]*+\))*+[^()]*+$)
/x
EOT;
```

The lookaheads assert that if there are any double-quotes, single-quotes or parentheses ahead of the current match position there's an even number of them, and the parens are in balanced pairs (no nesting allowed).  That's a quick-and-dirty way to ensure that the current match isn't occurring inside a pair of quotes or parens.

Of course, it assumes the input is well formed.  But on the subject of of well-formedness, what about escaped quotes within quotes?  What if you have quotes inside parens, or vice-versa?  Would this input be legal?

```
"not a \" quote", 'not a ) quote', (not ",' quotes)
```

If so, you've got a much more difficult job ahead of you.